# Python Probability Program - Odds of drawing x cards from x cards drawn from x cards in deck

Tags: python, probability

So the program works most of the time as intended. It seems to fail when there is a difference of only 1 card. For example, drawing 6 cards from a 40 card deck, and wanting 5 specific cards, this returns the value "0"

It works in other cases. For example, drawing 5 cards from a deck of 40, wanting 3 specific cards returns an answer of 1/988

All cards are unique and individual from each other.

```
from math import factorial
from fractions import Fraction


deckNo = int(input("Enter the number of cards in the deck: "))
cardsDrawn = int(input("Number of cards drawn : "))
cardNo = int(input("Enter the number of cards you want to draw: "))


cardDifference = cardsDrawn - cardNo
newDeckNo = deckNo - cardNo

finalOdds = (factorial(cardsDrawn) * factorial(newDeckNo)) / (factorial(cardDifference) * factorial(deckNo))
finalOdds = Fraction(finalOdds).limit_denominator(10000)

print(finalOdds)
```

Is this an error with the method I'm using for the probability? If so what should I replace it with?

EDIT: Sorry about that, is this okay?

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem with hard-coded values, please don't include how you get the values.  It matters little how you get them ... if it doesn't matter how you got them.

Comment: What zondo is trying to say is that this example isn't an [mcve].  We have to write our own code to even try it out - we have to write a function to call calcOdds the very least.  The best way to get help is to read about MCVE, and post one: you know if you did it right because it is short and cut and paste is enough to make it show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notations and the binomial coefficient function in scipy the probability to calculate is the following:

```
scipy.special.binom(deckNo-cardsNo,cardsDrawn -cardNo)/scipy.special.binom(deckNo,cardsDrawn)
```

Just notice that the simplified version of the above expression I calculated doesn't work fine for me as I assume python has troubles managing the factorials and does a much better job using the binom functions.